# Chaining actions sharing data in a do block

Tags: haskell, io

Ok, suppose I have an `IO` operation; `loadFile :: FilePath -> ByteString` which I process with `processData :: ByteString -> ProcessedData` being this operation pretty expesnive and I want to use this processed data in two actions like so:

```
main = do
{
   bytes <- loadFile "....";
   let data = processData bytes
   in printf (extractFoo data address1)
      printf (extractFoo data address2) -- Compiler error    
}
```

I know I can do this, which is basically not sharing `data` between both actions:

```
main = do
{
   bytes <- loadFile "....";
   let data = processData bytes
   in printf (extractFoo data address1);
   let data = processData bytes
   in printf (extractFoo data address2);    
}
```

How can I share `data` in both `printf`? I'm very new to Haskell and I am struggling with the IO monad. I'm trying to understand it but its a slow process up till now.

Comment: Start a new `do` block after `in`.

Comment: @Jubobs duh...(facepalm) Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Just remove the curly braces and use a plain `let`:

```
main = do
   bytes <- loadFile "...."
   let d = processData bytes
   printf (extractFoo d address1)
   printf (extractFoo d address2)
```

I renamed your `data` to `d` since `data` is a keyword in Haskell.